# NodeJs выдает /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, centos, centos7

Всем привет!
При выполнении `node -v` и `npm -v` выдает:

```
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
```

Node устанавливал через NVM.

```
->      v8.17.0
        v18.9.1
         system
default -> v18.9.1
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v18.9.1) (default)
stable -> 18.9 (-> v18.9.1) (default)
lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.20.1 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.17.1 (-> N/A)
```

Пробовал установить

```
yum install libstdc++.so.6

yum install libc.so.6
```

но это на ошибку ни как не повлияло.
Система Centos 7.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не то делаю. 
С такой ошибкой сталкиваюсь впервые

Answer (score 1):

С версии ноды 18 изменился процесс билда. Некоторые ОС не поддерживают его. Текущая LTS версия ноды должна работать.

Comment: Последняя из тех что запустилась без такой ошибки это 16.18.1